# Why does the same script work in Exchange Management Shell 2010 but not through C# with Powershell and Exchange Connection

Tags: c#, powershell, null, active-directory, exchange-server

I have the following powershell script I use with Exchange 2010 to get the forwarding email adresses

```
$fwds = get-mailbox | Where-Object { $_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null } | select Name, ForwardingAddress

foreach ($fwd in $fwds) 
{
    $fwd | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "ContactAddress" -value (Get-ADObject -Identity $(($fwd.ForwardingAddress).DistinguishedName) -Properties mail).mail
   

    if($fwd.ContactAddress)
    {
        #Maakt objecten aan die in C# uit te lezen zijn
        $properties = @{
            Name = $fwd.Name
            ContactAddress = $fwd.ContactAddress
        }   

        $o = New-Object psobject -Property $properties;

        # Dit zet het object bruikbaar als object in c#
        Write-Output $o
    }
}
```

When I run this in the Exchange Management Shell (2010) it works fine.. Yesterday I also were able to run this through Powershell in C#.

I use the following code for connecting after I open a runspace

```
                        PSCommand commandExchangePSSession = new PSCommand();
                        commandExchangePSSession.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
                        commandExchangePSSession.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
                        commandExchangePSSession.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", argUri);
                        commandExchangePSSession.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
                        commandExchangePSSession.AddParameter("Authentication", "Kerberos");

                        PSSessionOption sessionOption = new PSSessionOption();
                        sessionOption.SkipCACheck = true;
                        sessionOption.SkipCNCheck = true;
                        sessionOption.SkipRevocationCheck = true;
                        commandExchangePSSession.AddParameter("SessionOption", sessionOption);
```

Then I use a `Get-Session` command, followed by a `Import-Session`. After that I use `PowerShell.Create()` to create a new PowerShell Object to add the script into with:

```
                                var powershellExecScript = PowerShell.Create();
                                powershellExecScript.Commands.AddScript(tempTotalScript); 

                                powershellExecScript.Runspace = runspace;

                                Collection<PSObject> results = powershellExecScript.Invoke();
```

Where `tempTotalScript` is the script stated above... Yet when I run it I get errors that Identity can't be NULL.

```
Exception: System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
```

So I narrowed the problem down to `$(($fwd.ForwardingAddress).DistinguishedName`

The `$fwd.ForwardingAddress` works, it returns a valid value through C#. So this also means my powershell connection code is not invalid. But the `DistinguishedName` does not, it returns null. This is the reason I am getting errors running my code through C#.

When I try the same code in the Exchange Management Shell... the `DistinguishedName` property is not null and showing a proper distinguished name..

So my question is, why is the DistinguishedName property inside $fwd.ForwardingAddress not filled with a value when I run the code through C# Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a remote session returns serialized (also called dehydrated or string-ified) objects.  These do not maintain full fidelity to the original objects.  Usually, this is described as the removal of methods, but it can go beyond that. Typically, complex objects are somewhat flattened. Using this case as an example, in an Exchange Management Shell console, where the management tools are installed and properly loaded, the ForwardingAddress property is of type `[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.ADObjectId]`.

However, in a remote session established with the below command:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://<serverName>/powershell" -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession -Session $session
```

Then the forwarding address will be a simple string formatted as a canonical name.  This is usually the same as running the full fidelity object through the `.ToString()` method.

I haven't done any of this through C#, however, it is a big problem. We'll tend to develop in an environment that has our full tool-chain installed then deploy to an environment that doesn't.  There are 2 ways I've dealt with the problem.

1. Make an exception and develop under the same environmental
   circumstances you plan to deploy to.
2. Build logic into your code to detect the object type and act
   differently, something like below:

---

```
If( $ForwardingAddress.GetType().Fullname -is [String] ) {
    # Do Something... 
} 
Else {
    # Do something different...
}
```

#1 is obviously more simple.

#2 is better for continued development because you can run and test locally.  However, this can also get out of hand, as your program gets more complex and you have other objects to deal with, etc...  Not to mention there's overhead to checking the objects even before accommodating them.

Comment: If I use ```$test = get-contact $fwd.ForwardingAddress | select DistinguishedName``` I cant use it with ```write-ouput $test```. Yet when I directly ```write-ouput get-contact...``` it does work. Is this for the same reason?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you want to Select the string you'd have to use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`

Comment: I am able to use ```get-adobject``` with a filter on a canoncial name, so I can find the ADObject. Yet I notice the object has only the basic properties of name, guid, DN. I am not able to get a property like mail or sAMAccountname. Neither with ```Select-Object``` as you suggested. Is this because of serialization again?

Comment: Now, as far as properties are concerned simply add the `-Properties` parameter to the `Get-ADObject` command. use an array of attribute names as the argument. Example: `(Get-MailContact <IdentityString>).DistinguishedName | Get-ADObject -Properties "DisplayName","Description"`

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. The forwardingAddress property in the Get-Mailbox call at the top of the script, is serialized towards a canonicalName... So thats everything I had to find an ADObject for it. I spend some time on it today and were able to get all ad-objects and query on canonicalName and find the ADObject I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry about that. I deleted those other comments. Still not sure how you did the filter.  I don't have the broader code, but you can also select the DistinguishedName in the remote script block, where the objects are still full fidelity.  Something like `Get-Mailbox <MBID> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ForwardingAddress | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`.  However the previous property comment is valid, so if you've got a working filter you should run with it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is not the right answer.

Seems that `Get-ADObject` did not work in Exchange 2010. I had to use `get-contact`

```
#Exchange 2010 Script
$fwds = get-mailbox | Where-Object { $_.ForwardingAddress -ne $null } | select Name, ForwardingAddress, DeliverToMailboxAndForward

foreach ($fwd in $fwds) 
{

    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    $fwd | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name "ContactAddress" -value (get-contact $fwd.ForwardingAddress).WindowsEmailAddress
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"


    #Maakt objecten aan die in C# uit te lezen zijn

    if($fwd.ContactAddress)
    {
        $properties = @{
        Name = $fwd.Name
        ContactAddress = $fwd.ContactAddress
        DeliverToMailboxAndForward = $fwd.DeliverToMailboxAndForward
        }
        $o = New-Object psobject -Property $properties;

        # Dit zet het object bruikbaar als object in c#
        Write-Output $o
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `Get-ADObject` is from the ADDS RSAT tools, which include the ActiveDirectory module. AD cmdlets typically don't accept a canonical name for an identity parameter.  `Get-Contact` is working because it will accept either the `[ADObjectId]` or the string as the input to its `-Identity` parameter.  Check my answer for further explanation.

Comment: @Steven You are right, I have now have the same issue with the Exchange 2019.. my answer is not the answer. Your answer explains what really is going on. Thanks for sharing!